# Why does CnosDB take so much time to recover?

Tags: cnosdb

I am using Cnosdb v2.2. After writing about 60GB of data, I restarted the system, but even after 20 minutes of starting up, it is still in the recovery state. This situation seems unreasonable.

```
2023-05-10T02:40:04.616991783Z  INFO tskv::wal: WAL '67' starts write
2023-05-10T02:40:04.617089059Z  WARN tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal from seq '0'
2023-05-10T02:40:04.620295962Z  INFO tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal '_000001.wal' for seq 1 to 14461
2023-05-10T02:40:05.241918796Z  INFO tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal '_000003.wal' for seq 1 to 585864
2023-05-10T02:40:34.134274976Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631614464,"time":1683686434,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-05-10T02:41:04.134319213Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631614464,"time":1683686464,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-05-10T02:41:21.870404081Z  INFO tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal '_000004.wal' for seq 585865 to 1196801
2023-05-10T02:41:34.134160394Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631614464,"time":1683686494,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-05-10T02:42:04.135040084Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631614464,"time":1683686524,"status":"Healthy"}
.....
2023-05-10T03:21:33.937037575Z  INFO tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal '_000033.wal' for seq 15170419 to 15597199
2023-05-10T03:21:34.138472852Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :/cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631598080,"time":1683688924,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-05-10T03:22:34.134189394Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631598080,"time":1683688954,"status":"Healthy"}
2023-05-10T03:23:03.658475355Z  INFO tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal '_000034.wal' for seq 15597200 to 16027687
2023-05-10T03:23:04.141614130Z  INFO meta::store::state_machine: WRITE: /cluster_xxx/data_nodes_metrics/1001 :{"id":1001,"disk_free":21410631598080,"time":1683688984,"status":"Healthy"}
```